# Jekyll: site.url not interpreted in include tag

Tags: jekyll

I am using the following include tag in my posts:

```
{% include image.html url="{{ site.url }}/files/image.png" description="Figure 1.  image description." %}
```

The included `image.html` looks as follows:

```
<figure>
  <img src="{{ include.url }}" alt="{{ include.description }}">
  <figcaption>{{ include.description }}</figcaption>
</figure>
```

In `_config.yml` I use `url: "http://domain.com"`.

However, when serving my Jekyll blog, `{{ site.url }}` is not interpreted, resulting in:

```
<figure>
  <img src="{{ site.url }}/files/image.png" alt="Figure 1.  image description.">
  <figcaption>Figure 1.  image description.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Can anyone tell me why interpretation does not work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use relative url

```
{% capture imgFullUrl %}{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/files/image.png{% endcapture %}
{% include img.html url=imgFullUrl description="Figure 1.  image description." %}
```

To use full url

```
{% capture imgRelativeUrl %}{{ site.baseurl }}/files/image.png{% endcapture %}
{% include img.html url=imgRelativeUrl description="Figure 1.  image description." %}
```

Answer (score 0):

### First possible solution:

### *(if your Jekyll site is at the root of the domain)*

You don't need to use `{{ site.url }}` at all.

Technically, if the HTML is on a page somewhere at http://domain.com,

```
<img src="/files/image.png">
```

is the same as

```
<img src="http://domain.com/files/image.png">
```

---

### Second possible solution:

### (if your Jekyll site root is in a subdirectory like http://domain.com/jekyll/, so you can't just use `/files/image.png`)

Don't pass `{{ site.url }}` from your actual pages to the include. Prepend it inside the include instead:

```
{% include image.html url="/files/image.png" description="Figure 1.  image description." %}
```

and then

```
<figure>
  <img src="{{ site.url }}{{ include.url }}" alt="{{ include.description }}">
  <figcaption>{{ include.description }}</figcaption>
</figure>
```

If you want to display images from external URLs as well, you can't just slap `{{ site.url }}` in front of **every** image URL.
In this case, you could check if the image URL begins with `/` and only prepend `{{ site.url }}` when this is the case:

```
<figure>
  {% assign tmp = include.url | truncate: 1, '' %}
  <img src="{% if tmp == '/' %}{{ site.url }}{% endif %}{{ include.url }}" alt="{{ include.description }}">
  <figcaption>{{ include.description }}</figcaption>
</figure>
```